# Mathematical Analysis advice

Tags: analysis, proof-verification

Claim: Let $\delta>0, n\in N.  $ Then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} I_{n} $exists, where $ I_{n}=\int_{0}^{\delta} \frac{\sin\ nx}{x}  dx  $

Proof: $f(x) =\frac{\sin\ nx}{x}$ has a removable discontinuity at $x=0$ and so we let $f(0) =n$

$x = \frac{t}{n}$ is continuous and monotone on $t\in[0,n\delta]$, hence, $ I_{n}=\int_{0}^{n\delta} \frac{\sin\ t}{t}  dt  $

For all  $p\geq 1$, given any $\epsilon \gneq 0,  \exists n_{0} \gneq \frac{\epsilon}{2\delta}$ such that $\forall n\gneq n_{0}$,   $|I_{n+p}-I_{n}| =  \left\lvert\int_{n\delta}^{(n+p)\delta} \frac{\sin\ t}{t}  dt \right\lvert  \leq \int_{n\delta}^{(n+p)\delta} \frac{\left\lvert\sin t\ \right\lvert}{t}  dt = \frac{1} {n\delta}\int_{n\delta}^{M} \left\lvert\sin t\right\lvert dt \ \leq \frac{2} {n\delta} \lneq \epsilon$ ,  for some $M \in [n\delta, (n+p)\delta]$, by Bonnet's  theorem

Is my proof valid? Thank you.

Comment: You have to choose $n$ before you fix $p$. You need to use the fact that $\sin$ has positive and negative values to show the convergence.

Comment: Thanks for advice, I have made the necessary amendments. Is the proof valid now?

Comment: You must choose $n$ before $p$. For all $\varepsilon > 0$, there is an $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that _for all_ $n \geqslant n_0$ and all $p \in \mathbb{N}$ you have $\lvert I_n - I_{n+p}\rvert < \varepsilon$. And since $\int_M^\infty \frac{\lvert \sin t\rvert}{t}\,dt = +\infty$, you cannot have a valid proof if you have an absolute value inside the integral (unless you get a different integrand, e.g. by partial integration).

Comment: Hi, noted. Kindly refer to my amendments. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You have *almost* proved that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}I_n=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin t}{t}dt$$
so prove also that this integral (*limit*) is convergent (*finite*) by integration by parts.

Answer (score 2):

I think your proof approach works, but a more direct/intuitive proof may be to work with that fact you showed

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} I_n = \lim_{t \to \infty} \int_0^t \frac{\sin x}{x} dx$$

and you can break up this integral into alternating regions where $\sin t$ is first positive, then negative, then positive, etc, and then note that the sum you get satisfies the alternating series test because $1/x$ is decreasing.

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest a alternative path. Prove that $$\lim_{a\to 0^+}\lim_{b \to\infty}\int_a^b\frac{\sin x}xdx$$
exists as follows: integrating by parts

$$\int_a^b \frac{\sin x}xdx=\left.\frac{1-\cos x}x\right|_a^b-\int_a^b\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}dx$$

Then use $$\frac{1-\cos h}h\stackrel{h\to 0}\to 0$$ $$\frac{1-\cos h}{h^2}\stackrel{h\to 0}\to\frac 1 2$$ $$\int_1^\infty\frac{dt}{t^2}=1<+\infty$$

Then it will follow your limit is indeed that integral, since changing variables and since $\delta >0$ $$\int_0^{n\delta}\frac{\sin x}xdx\to\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}xdx$$

Then it remains to find what that improper Riemann integral equals to. One can prove it equals $\dfrac \pi2$. First, one uses that

$$1 +2\sum_{k=1}^n\cos kx=\frac{\sin \left(n+\frac 1 2\right)x}{\sin\frac x  2}$$

from where it follows $$\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin \left(n+\frac 1 2\right)x}{\sin\frac x  2}dx=\pi$$ since all the cosine integrals vanish. Now, the function $$\frac{2}{t}-\frac{1}{\sin\frac t 2}$$ is continuous on $[0,\pi]$. Thus, by the Riemann Lebesgue Lemma, $$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \int_0^\pi  {\sin \left( {n + \frac{1}{2}} \right)x\left( {\frac{2}{x} - {{\left( {\sin \frac{x}{2}} \right)}^{ - 1}}} \right)dx}  = 0$$

It follows that $$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \int_0^\pi  {\frac{{\sin \left( {n + \frac{1}{2}} \right)x}}{x}dx}  = \frac{\pi }{2}$$ so $$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \int_0^{\pi \left( {n + \frac{1}{2}} \right)} {\frac{{\sin x}}{x}dx}  = \frac{\pi }{2}$$

Since we know the integral already exists, we conclude $$\int_0^\infty  {\frac{{\sin x}}{x}dx}  = \frac{\pi }{2}$$