# Showing limit exists for integral of $(\sin x)/x$

Tags: calculus, integration

Suppose we have a function like 
$$f(x)=\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$$

Consider
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\int_1^tf(x)dx$$
According to Wolfram, this limit [exists](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+t+to+infinity+%28Integrate+sinx%2Fx+from+x%3D1+to+t%29) but has a value that cannot be expressed in a simple form. Clearly we will not be able to compute it by hand, but is it possible to show that the limit exists at all?

Comment: I know this isn't *exactly* what you are asking, but it can be shown through complex analysis techniques (contour integrals), that $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x} dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the limit is $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin t}tdt-\int_0^1\frac{\sin t}t dt$$ which is what Wolphram gives. Do you know how to show that $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin t}tdt$$ exists? This is a famous integral, so you might easily find literature about it. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465096/mathematical-analysis-advice/465179#465179) I provide a way to do so, and show it equals $\dfrac \pi 2$.

Comment: I see that you proved $\int_0^{\pi \left( {n + \frac{1}{2}} \right)} {\frac{{\sin x}}{x}dx}  = \frac{\pi }{2}$, but where did you actually prove the integral exists?

Comment: You're integrating a continuous function.

Comment: I'm sorry -- I forgot to copy over the limit. I meant to ask: I see you proved $\lim_{n \to \infty } \int_0^{\pi \left( {n + \frac{1}{2}} \right)} {\frac{{\sin x}}{x}dx}  = \frac{\pi }{2}$, but where did you actually prove that the limit (i.e. the integral to infinity $\int_0^\infty\dfrac{\sin x}{x}dx$) exists?

Comment: I had a (faulty) answer that addressed this, but I like Pedro's answer more. To see the integral exists more directly, break it up into the humps and then show that each hump is "small" and alternating sign.

Comment: @PaulS. One uses the comparison test on $0\leqslant 1-\cos x \leqslant 2$ with $$\int_1^\infty \frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}dx$$ plus the limits I explain in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I have a solution using infinite series to solve this...
(Ah..it was mentioned by  @Callus "15mins" before in the above comments while I was still struggling with Latex...)

Note that since 
$$
\text{$\forall $a,b$\in $ R b$>$a$\geqslant $1, $\exists $}\int_a^b \frac{\sin (x)}{x} \, dx
$$
We can reduce the limit to this:
$$
\text{$\quad $ $\exists $ }
\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty } \int_1^t \frac{\sin (x)}{x} \, dx
\text{ $\Leftrightarrow \exists $}
\underset{k\rightarrow \infty }{\text{  }\lim }\int_{\pi }^{(2k+1)\pi } \frac{\sin (x)}{x} \, dx
$$
This allows us to split the integral into parts and change the problem into the sum of an alternating series.

$\underset{k\rightarrow \infty }{\text{  }\lim }\int_{\pi }^{(2k+1)\pi } \frac{\sin (x)}{x} \, dx$

$
\text{= }
\int_{\pi }^{2\pi } \frac{\sin (x)}{x} \, dx+\int_{2\pi }^{3\pi } \frac{\sin (x)}{x} \, dx+\text{...}+\int_{2\text{k$\pi $}}^{(2k+1)\pi } \frac{\sin (x)}{x} \, dx
\text{+...}
$

$
=-\int _{\pi }^{2\pi }\left|\frac{\sin (x)}{x}\right|dx+\int _{2\pi }^{3\pi }|\frac{\sin (x)}{x}|dx-\text{...}-\int _{(2k-1)\pi }^{2\text{k$\pi $}}|\frac{\sin (x)}{x}|dx+\int _{2\text{k$\pi $}}^{(2k+1)\pi }|\frac{\sin (x)}{x}|dx
$

$
=
\sum _{m=1}^{\infty } (-1)^m\int _{\text{m$\pi $}}^{(m+1)\pi }\left|\frac{\sin (x)}{x}\right|dx
$

$
=
\sum _{m=1}^{\infty } (-1)^m\alpha _m, \alpha _m=\int _{\text{m$\pi $}}^{(m+1)\pi }\left|\frac{\sin (x)}{x}\right|dx
$

Then it's easy to see that $\alpha _m>\alpha _{m+1}$
and $\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty } \alpha _m=0.$

Thus it passes the "Leibniz Test"(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) and therefore it converges.